# sass (or css), add %width as part of height style

Tags: css, sass

I have sort of an odd scenario here, I am setting a grid system in an App I'm building (using sass for my stylings) that has it's gutters set by % screen width. The problem I am having is the heights are hard coded and I'm wondering if I can hard code them and add in the % gutter (screen width %)

So the **logic** of what I'm trying to do is like so:

```
.item
    height: 600 + (1% width);
```

Is something like this possible in sass (or css)?

Comment: SASS can't detect screen width. You possibly need some JavaScript here. Or an awful workaround would be to setup media queries for each popular screen widths and inside it attach ``height: 600 + 1% of width`` for each screen width.

Comment: Javascript would be the best, pretty much all mobile phones support it by now

Comment: You should be use javascript. Sass or css can't do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [view Port units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) and [calc()](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc) to do so. This is plain css.

```
.item {
    height: calc(600px + 1vw)
}
```

**Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9kq3wb5q/**

Comment: Just curious, is this in any way bad for performance? Thanks regardless, it seems to work great!

Comment: i have no benchmarks for this. it will certenly make the browser think, but i think this is the fastest option you will find.